# Asterisk (*) is not working in VSCodes tasks.json

Tags: c, bash, visual-studio-code, gcc

When I try to run a C project with multiple modules it by default only compiles the selected module. I tried editing the tasks.json to compile every C and header file in a folder but it just passes the asterisk as an asterisk to my command line.

I edited the tasks.json and tried to build the project with the following output:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -f diagnostics-color=always -g /home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/main.c /home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/*.c /home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/*.h -o /home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgdRy3t.o: in function `main':
/home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/main.c:4: multiple definition of `main'; /tmp/ccW8LBPU.o:/home/user/VSCodeProjects/multimodule/main.c:4: first defined here
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück

Build finished with error(s).
```

As seen here it just uses the asterisk when running the gcc command instead of addressing all .c and .h files in the folder.
I already searched for the issue and found some issues e.g. this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16865) on the VSCode GitHub page, but none of the solutions seemed to work. Most of the answers I found don't apply here, as I'm already using version 2.0.0.

Contents of main.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int main(void)
{
    printTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of test.c:

```
#include "test.h"
#include<stdio.h>

void printTest(){
    printf("Test");
}
```

Contents of test.h:

```
#if !defined(TEST_H)
#define TEST_H

void printTest();

#endif // TEST_H
```

Contents of tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "${fileDirname}/*.c",
                "${fileDirname}/*.h",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: works fine for me. What's your OS and your system's default shell?