# How to fix "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" in this case?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, linker, mingw

I have 3 modules, but apparently there is a linker issue.

`main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_functions.h"

int main() {
    char source[] = "Hallo";
    char destination[20];

    manual_strcpy(destination, source);

    printf("Source: %s\n", source);
    printf("Destination: %s\n", destination);
    

    return 0;
}
```

`strcpy.c`

```c
#include "my_functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void manual_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    int i = 0;

    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }

    dest[i] = '\0';
}

int countO(char* str) {
    char *result;
    int count = 0;

    result = strchr(str, '-');
    while (result != NULL) {
        result++;
        if (*result == 'o' || *result == 'O') {
            count++;
        }
        result = strchr(result, '-');
    }

    return count;
}
```

`my_functions.h`

```c
#ifndef STRCPY_MANUAL_H
#define STRCPY_MANUAL_H

void manual_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
int countO(char* str);

#endif
```

When I try to run main.c, this is the result:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\ccuz4VGE.o:main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `manual_strcpy'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using `VScode` with `MinGW`.
They are all in the same folder.
My `tasks.json` in the folder `.vscode` looks like this:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\c-project\\strcpy\\*.c",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\c-project\\strcpy\\*.h",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\c-project\\strcpy\\main.c",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\c-project\\strcpy\\strcpy_manual.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I just can't find a solution to this problem, what can I do?

Comment: What is the source file really named? `strcpy.c` (as stated in the question) or `strcpy_manual.c` (as stated in the configuration file)? Or perhaps even something else?

Comment: Do you have the `gcc` command issued that raised the error message?

Comment: What is the command line that is executed when you try to build? I am not sure if wildcards work that way in VS Code

Comment: Also, the header file, you include `my_functions.h`, but you have header guards using `STRCPY_MANUAL_H`? Please be consistent.

Comment: @Gerhardh related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74390858/11107541

Comment: You should not add header files to the list of files to compile. They are normally not meant to be compiled directly.

Comment: In Lunix shells, the shell is responsible to replace the wildcard with a list of file names. On Windows, the wildcard is passed to the called program unmodified. That might be your issue. You should change your config file to add all files separately. With your list, you might end up including `main.c` and `strcpy_manual.c` twice causing other errors.

Comment: Hint: For SO to work properly, you are supposed to respond to feedback from comments.